# CakePHP - HABTM with predefined Model

Tags: validation, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models: Bar HABTM Foo. Now I have bars_foos join table with some additional fields.

When I add new Bar with some Foo associations or vice versa, I need to run many validation checks, whether the new associations are kosher. Checks are based on the additional fields defined and already saved associations.

Where should I run these validations? In Bar/Foo controller? Or should I create BarsFoo model with validation rules?

When I keep HABTM relationship to get all the auto-magic from Cake, I cannot find a way to tell Cake to use my own predefined BarsFoo model with validations rules. Cake creates its own virtual model and ignores mine.

Or should I (in this specific case) break HABTM into hasMany-belongsTo-hasMany relationship, where I can use my own BarsFoo model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your join model using the `with` key and create your validations there:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Bar' => array(
        …
        'with' => 'BarFoos'
    )
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

Comment: Well, I have tried this, but Cake ignores my model anyway. I have bars_foos table, Cake auto-creates BarsFoo model for me, but when I create bars_foo.php model with BarsFoo class and specify it with "with => 'BarsFoo'", Cake won't even try to load the class.

Comment: Oh, silly me! I had to specified "with" in both models. Thank you! Now everything is working perfectly.